# Form Authentication in JSP

Tags: java, forms, jsp, jsp-tags, form-authentication

I want to Setup form authentication in my JSP website `without creating any folder`. Can someone Suggest how to do this. ? thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Add login-config section in your web.xml. This is sample usages,

```
    <login-config>
      <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
      <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/fail_login.html</form-error-page>
      </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
```

If you want to know details of Form-Based Authentication, check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncby/index.html).

Comment: The example showing it needs a folder. My Question is can i set form based authentication without a folder. I means i do not want to create amy folder of resources. All resources are on the root location of web. How can i do that..?

Answer (score 0):

Use Servlet Authentication Feature.  It uses JAAS security, which is implemented by most of the Servlet containers like Tomcat, Websphere, Glassfish.

[Look here for the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182356/standard-form-authentification-java-servlets/11183774#11183774).

Comment: The example showing it needs a folder. My Question is can i set form based authentication without a folder. I means i do not want to create amy folder of resources. All resources are on the root location of web. How can i do that..?