# Session management in Servlets and JSP

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, servlets, servlet-filters

How to use sessions throughout all the servlets and JSPs in a project?

When I go to one of my JSP pages, which exists in my project, writing directly the JSP file name in URL, like `localhost:8080/XYZ/abc.jsp`, without validating login, the JSP page is opening in the browser.

How could I manage the JSP pages and servlets so that there will be no access to any page without login authentication?

Comment: check these blog post it may be useful     http://brendangraetz.wordpress.com/2010/06/17/use-servlet-filters-for-user-authentication/

Comment: @JavaPlayer This link was already mentioned 19 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15826014/814702 ))

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the way to do this is to build a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html).  This can be used to run code before and after a request is handled by a servlet or JSP.  You can build a filter which checks that a user's session is valid and, if not, redirects the user to a login page or an "unauthorised" page.  This will also save you from adding authentication logic to every JSP file you want to protect.

Maybe [this blog post](http://brendangraetz.wordpress.com/2010/06/17/use-servlet-filters-for-user-authentication/) would be helpful.

Comment: +1. As an addition, here is a local SO *servlet-filters* tag info page with examples: [Servlet Filters](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info)

Comment: It is ok but I have many servlets and many jsps in my project. How to manage a filter among all those servlets and jsps

Answer (score 0):

Use Servlet Authentication and Secure your web pages using Servlet Security.

Please read here.

[How to secure my java web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678959/how-to-secure-my-java-web-application)